# How to find the possible positive integer values of $k$ and $n$ in a binomial expansion.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Given that $(1 + kx)^4(1 + x)^n = 1 + 13x + 74x^2 + \cdots + k^4x^{n + 4}$, find the possible positive integer values of $k$ and $n$.

**My working:**

$$(1 + kx)^4(1 + x)^n = (1 + 4kx + 6k^2x^2 + 4k^3x^3 + k^4x^4)(1 + x)^n$$

This can be written as

$$(1 + x)^n + 4kx(1 + x)^n + 6k^2x^2(1 + x)^n + 4k^3x^3(1 + x)^n + k^4x^4(1 + x)^n$$

Therefore, the coefficient of $x$ in this expansion is

$$n + 4k = 13$$

Another equation in $n$ and $k$ is needed in order to solve. Hence we find the coefficient of $x^2$ in this expansion

$$\binom{n}{2} + 4kn + 6k^2 = 74$$

Furthermore, this simplifies to

$$n(n - 1) + 4k(2n + 3k) = 148 = 2^2 \times 37$$

Subbing $n = 13 - 4k$ we get

$$(13 - 4k)(12 - 4k) + 4k(11k + 26) = 2^2 \times 37$$

Which simplifies to

$$15k^2 + k + 2 = 0$$

This quadratic has non-integer roots so does not comply with the restrictions set by the question.

From here I am unable to progress. What is the next step in the solution?

Comment: You've got two equations in the two unknowns $k,n$. Eliminate $n$ between them, for example.

Comment: Recheck your substitution, in particular the $(11 k + 26)$ term.

Comment: I have corrected my mistake. @dxiv

Comment: Check one more time. $2(13-4k) + 3k \ne 11k + 26$.

Comment: I hate when I make these silly errors. It should be $4k(2n + 3k) = 4k(26 -5k)$